# Boost log error

Tags: boost-log, gcc4.5

**Hi all!**

**I try to build with gcc 4.5 application which is used boost log (boost 1.53).  And I got the following error:**

In file included from Modules/3rdParty/Boost/Include/boost/log/common.hpp:27:0,

from Modules/Core/Common/Include/Common/Logger.h:5

Modules/3rdParty/Boost/Include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp: In member function 'void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger::push_record_unlocked(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&&)':

Modules/3rdParty/Boost/Include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:268:46: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record(boost::remove_reference::type&)'

Modules/3rdParty/Boost/Include/boost/log/core/core.hpp:306:49: note: candidate is: void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&&)

**Everything is working well when I use gcc 4.7 but I need gcc 4.5. How can I fix it?
Thank you!**